# If a moving charge itself makes magnetic field, then how can we study about force on a moving charge in Magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

If a moving charge itself makes magnetic field, then how can we study about force on a moving charge in Magnetic field

Isn't it a contradictory statement?

Comment: You should take a look at the phenomenon known as Induction and maybe take a look at Lenz's Law too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be confusing the magnetic field of the moving charge and the external magnetic field.

Let's say, the external magnatic field B2 is caused by a steady electrical current in a straight wire. And the charge is just standing next to it. There will be no force on the charge or the wire.

Now when the charge gets moving relative to the wire, it also creates it's own magnetic field B1.

B1 has nothing to do with force acting on the charge itself. B1 only exerts a force on the wire in which a current is.

The magnetic force acting on the charge is only due to the magnetic field of the wire (B2) and the speed and direction of the charge.

Nevertheless, the force exerted to the wire by the magnetic field (B1) of the charge and the force exerted on the moving charge by the magnetic field (B2) of the wire must be equal.

You could take a look at this video which explains magnetic forces in terms of special relativity just to have a simple idea about contractions and transformations:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1TKSfAkWWN0

You got confused about the magnetism and it's a sign that you are on the right path. Good luck with your studies.

Comment: Wow I didnt knew Veritasium had a video on this , he is amazing :D                                             Thanks a lot sir , your answer cleared my doubt :)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in pointing out that the charge has its own magnetic field. From maxwell's 4th eqn we have:

$\nabla \times \vec B = \mu_0. \vec J + \frac{1}{c^2}. \frac{\partial \vec E}{\partial t}$.

FOr a moving charge, $\vec J$ is zero, leaving only the second term. You can see, that for non relativistic speeds, $\frac{\partial \vec E}{\partial t}$ is much lesser than $c^2$, for which purpose in the expression for the total magnetic field in all space, we neglect this trivial contribution, and thus have the lorentz force of

$\vec F = q(\vec E + \vec v \times \vec B)$

However, for charges moving at relativistic speeds, we can no longer neglect the particles own magnetic field, and applying suitable transformations to the equations, we end up with the more corect version of lorentz force :

$\vec F = q.\gamma (\vec E + \vec v \times \vec B)$

Where $\gamma$ is the famous 'lorentz factor' given by

$\gamma ^2= \frac{1}{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$ (i may be wrong here, so please look up the lorentz factor)

Comment: Note that in the limit v much less than c, $\gamma$ tends to 1

Comment: Thanks man but Im studying highschool physics so dont know much about lorentz factor , our chapter is magnetic effect of current , in which they first tell us that moving charge produces Magnetic Field , and then suddenly there is topic of Lorentz Force which tells us about the force on a moving charge by magnetic field , What I have figured out is that , the magnetic field produced by moving charge , applies force on moving charge that means indirectly a moving charge just applies force on itself while producing magnetic field , God this is confusing :/

Comment: You will need to understand the maths to grasp the situatiom better in the end. Just remember that we neglect this field for all calculations in high school.

Comment: This answer is all wrong, I'm afraid.

Comment: Will you please explain why? I do not deny the possibility of an incorrect answer.